# sfdisk on extended and Linux swap partitions

Tags: partitioning, restore

Is it possible to perform sfdisk on Extended and Linux swap partitions?
or maybe I need to remove the lines with /dev/cciss/c0d0p4 and /dev/cciss/c0d0p7 ? from the file c0d0-partition-info.sfdisk,

For example, consider the following partition info (using the commands):

```
   sfdisk --force /dev/cciss/c0d0 < c0d0-partition-info.sfdisk
```

>

```
    more c0d0-partition-info.sfdisk


    /dev/cciss/c0d0p1 : start=       63, size=   401562, Id=83, bootable
    /dev/cciss/c0d0p2 : start=   401625, size=266331943, Id=83
    /dev/cciss/c0d0p3 : start=266733568, size=266342400, Id=83
    /dev/cciss/c0d0p4 : start=533078016, size= 52783104, Id= 5 Extended
    /dev/cciss/c0d0p5 : start=533080064, size= 25511936, Id=83
    /dev/cciss/c0d0p6 : start=558594048, size= 16771072, Id=82
    /dev/cciss/c0d0p7 : start=575367168, size= 10489856, Id=83 Linux swap / Solaris
```